# Grails - Set "disabled" attribute name and value in GSP

Tags: grails, taglib, gsp, html, setattribute

I´m trying to do this without success:

```
<g:textField title="${title}" ${disabled} />
```

I want to apply a **disabled** attribute, ONLY if the ${disabled} variable is TRUE.
I don't want to use conditionals, because in other views I got a lot of code and using IF statements, will be a chaos.

The other thing is applying the attribute like this:

```
<g:textField title="${title}" disabled="${disabled}" />
```

But when I put the **disabled** attribute, no mather the content of the variable, It just always disables the field.

Comment: Please edit your problem statement to plainly state your intent.  Your comment on gotomanners' answer seems to conflict with your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your **${disabled}** variable should be returning "disabled" not TRUE for that to work.

### EDIT

I tried this out and saw the problem with it always being disabled no matter the value. Apparently the mere presence of the disabled keyword disables the field and the value assigned to that keyword is only a dummy value.

Anyway, Here's a fix.

- Create a Taglib class(if you don't have one already)
- define your own textfield tag as such...

  ```
  def myTextField = { attrs, body ->
    def title = attrs.remove("title")
    def isDisabled = attrs.remove("disabled")

    if ("true".equals(isDisabled)) {
      out << """<input title="${title}" disabled="${isDisabled}" """
      attrs.each { k,v ->
          out << k << "=\"" << v << "\" "
        }
      out << "/>"
    } else {
      out << """<input title="${title}" """
      attrs.each { k,v ->
          out << k << "=\"" << v << "\" "
        }
      out << "/>" 
    }
  }
  ```
- in your gsp, call your textfield tag like so

  ```
  <g:myTextField title="${title}" disabled="${disabled}" />
  ```
- adding extra attributes like so is also valid

  ```
  <g:myTextField class="title" name="theName" value="theValue" title="${title}" disabled="${disabled}" />
  ```
- make sure your **${disabled}** variable returns "true" or "false" as strings this time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't really care about the disable variable and its content. I just need to write an attribute, ie: 
<g:textField title="${title}" ${disabled} />
where ${disabled} contains a String: 'title="Input title"'

Answer (score 8):

if you don't like gotomanners' solution (which seems perfectly valid to me)

```
<g:textField title="${title}" ${(disabled)?"disabled":""} />
```

Comment: But is valid html - which is what most of us are creating these days (if you come across this answer now many years later)